# The login page on the Data Explorer doesn't show the form field to put the username

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, login

I tried to log in to the Data Explorer site, but when I click on the icon for the OpenID provider, I don't see the form field to enter the username.

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot shows what I see after I click on the ClickPass icon.

I then entered the URL, which was auto-completed by the browser, but I don't get the right account, as the account shows [jon.doe6347](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6346/jon-doe6347) and I was not advised I was creating a new account.

The OpenID I entered is the correct one, as it is visible in the other accounts I have on SE sites. I tried logging in with my other OpenID provider, but all I got is to be logged in as [jon.doe6348](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6347), even though I used the correct URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed, now. I tried right 5 minutes ago, and I could log in using Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]