# Data.SE: I am jon.doe6817

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, data-explorer

Why do I get [@jon.doe6817](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6816/jon-doe6817?order_by=saved) for signing in with my Google OpenID? I get my 'normal' [@Muntoo](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5854/muntoo) account after signing in with Yahoo. I doubt @jon.doe6817 'stole' my Gmail password. (It is ~30 `noasklertxkcd7h1sd035n7m4k3$3nse#+` long.)

**EDIT:** BTW, I have a few favorites/queries on Data.SE. These were not present when I logged in with @jon.doe6817.

**EDIT 2:** (2 Jan 2012) This happened again. I logged in via Google at https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login.

Comment: I've pinged waffles, but I *believe* this is just unknown name etc (OpenID isn't always very forthcoming with such)

Comment: It happened to me time ago. When trying to log in on data.SE, I was always logged-in as joedoe.[some-ransom-number]; then, all in a sudden, I was able to log in, and appear as kiamlaluno. I was not able to track if it were a problem with the OpenID provider, though.

Comment: My report was [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98779/the-login-page-on-the-data-explorer-doesnt-show-the-form-field-to-put-the-usern).

Comment: Did you mix HTTP and HTTPS URLs? There used to be a bug with that, although I can't find it now and I think it may have been fixed.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108416/has-something-happened-to-the-data-se-login-credentials/108417#108417

Comment: @PopularDemand I just used http://data.stackexchange.com/ (no HTTPS), which links to http://data.stackexchange.com/account/login (no HTTPS).

Comment: I meant your OpenID URL, not the URL you used to access SEDE. Rebecca's answer to the question @jonsca linked explains what I meant, and states that that particular issue has in fact been fixed.

Comment: working on a mega cleanup at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a mega merge and merged your accounts and a ton of others, if any merges remain ensure your email is set to the same email on **all dupe accounts** and ping me via a comment here.